# Invalid block tag 'Static...' Django 3.1

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I hope my message finds you well.
I have this error: Invalid block tag on line 8: 'Static'/Style/style.css''. I followed all the solutions I found here and it didn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your reference to the css file is wrong. Try this:

```
href="{% Static 'Style/style.css' %}
```

also it is common practice to use lowercase variables in such case like so:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = 
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Additionally, I recommend to change your directory to `static/CSS/your_styles.css`